# Windows 7 keyboard not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I'm running windows 7 64 bits, my problem consist of a keyboard issue witch not working perfectly, it just need to hit more than one time the key to be able to write a letter.
I was using windows 7 32 bits. I formatted my c drive, and reinstall windows 7 64 bits but i'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Try a different keyboard and if you don't face the issue with it, get a new keyboard.

Comment: I tried new keyboards, but i face the same issue.

Comment: Is this problem specific to Windows? Does this affect all the keys on the keyboard (including arrow keys?). If it affects all keys equally, try entering the BIOS menu and use the arrow keys there and see if you still need to press the keys twice to get the machine to register them. If you do, then there's probably something wrong with your hardware. In that case, update your question with more information (laptop/desktop model and make, BIOS version, when did you start facing this problem, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try booting in safe mode and see what happens if the issue prevails either perform a clean install of windows in previous 32 bit mode !

Comment: I tried booting in safe mode but i have the same issue with different keyboards whose working in other PCs.

Comment: @computerSPro try downloading ubuntu and make a live CD or USB and boot and see if the problem is still in Ubuntu ? If the problem goes away make a clean install of Windows.